# Accessing objects in an array returned by National Rail UK OpenLDBWS

Tags: php

I am trying to access data from an array produced using the National Rail OpenLDBWS but no matter what I try I am not able to return some data.
if I echo out :

```
echo "LOCATION :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->locationName; // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
echo "OPERATOR :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->operator; // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
echo "DATE :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->generatedAt; // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
echo "CRS :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->crs; // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
echo "PLATFORM :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->platformAvailable;// THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
echo "DESTINATION :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->locationName;  // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
```

How can I access the data that is not returned in my echo staetment.

```
require("OpenLDBWS.php");
$OpenLDBWS = new OpenLDBWS("MY NATIONAL RAIL TOKEN");
$result = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepartureBoard(1, "GLC");
header ("Content-Type: text/plain")
```

The complete array returned:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetStationBoardResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [generatedAt] => 2021-07-09T09:19:32.4132656+01:00 // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
        [locationName] => Glasgow Central // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
        [crs] => GLC // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
        [platformAvailable] => 1 // THIS  DATA IS RETURNED
        [trainServices] => stdClass Object
            (
                [service] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [std] => 09:18 // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [etd] => On time // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [platform] => 8R // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [operator] => ScotRail // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [operatorCode] => SR // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [serviceType] => train // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [serviceID] => I/U30cUsp5Jk+ANreHmh2Q== // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [rsid] => SR916200 // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                [origin] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [location] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [locationName] => Glasgow Central // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                                        [crs] => GLC // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [destination] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [location] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                                    (
                                                        [locationName] => East Kilbride // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                                        [crs] => EKL // THIS  DATA IS NOT RETURNED
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Why should `$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->operator` return anything, the `trainServices` object does not have a property `operator` … You need to go to `services` first, and then access the array element at this position via index. _Then_ you can start accessing the properties _that_ object contains.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**
1.

```
$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->operator
```

2. 

```
$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices['operator']
```

3. 

```
$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices[0]['operator']
```

Comment: Hi I have tried your reply but none return data. I have also tried:echo "OPERATOR1 :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->service->operator;
echo "OPERATOR2 :" .$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->service->operator;. Again, no data reurned.

Comment: $result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->service[0]['operator']

Comment: I even tried that "$result->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->service[0]['operator'] " still not not return data.

Comment: I am at a complete loss. I have tried all combinations of the $result->, apart from the one that works but I can;t find out what it is I am doing wrong. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi, I am getting no errors in the console or in the php errors log.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested this is what I came up with and it works.

```
require("OpenLDBWS.php");
$OpenLDBWS = new OpenLDBWS("MY TOKEN");
$response = $OpenLDBWS->GetDepBoardWithDetails(1,"GLC");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

//print_r ($response);

if (isset($response->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->service))
    {
   
     foreach($response->GetStationBoardResult->trainServices->service as $service)
    {
     
    $destinations = array();
    foreach($service->destination->location as $location)
    {
        $destinations[] = $location->locationName;
        $desticrs[] = $location->crs;
    }
      
    $recordtime = substr($response->GetStationBoardResult->generatedAt, 0, 16);
    $origin_location = $response->GetStationBoardResult->locationName;
    $origin_crs= $response->GetStationBoardResult->crs;
    $time = $service->std;
    $serviceID = $service->serviceID;
    $operator = $service->operator;
    $dest = implode($destinations);
    $dest_crs = implode($desticrs);
    $plat = $service->platform;
    $est= $service->etd;
    $datetime = substr($recordtime, 0, 16);
    $recordtime = str_replace('T',' ',$recordtime); 
    $recordtime = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($recordtime));
    // Perform database insert
}
```